# File Not Found Error while reading from S3 - PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

I am trying to read a **.csv** file on s3 into a PySpark dataframe in Glue. However it keeps on failing with `"AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3://kp-landing-dev/input/kp/kp/export_incr_20230611183316.csv"` error. I have verified the path and the file a hundred times and they do exist (on s3). I am breaking my head over this.

I have even built a function (below) to check if the file exists on s3 and it runs successfully and returns the file-name correctly. Hence, bit confused as to where I am going wrong.

```
def get_file_name(bucket_name, directory_remote, file_name):
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=f"{directory_remote}/{file_name}")
        for obj in objects['Contents']:
            return(obj['Key'].split("/")[-1])
    except:
        print("Error encountered in get_file_name")

bucket = "kp-landing-dev"
directory_remote = "input/kp/kp"
toName_csv = "export_incr_20230611183316"
myfile = get_file_name(bucket, directory_remote, toName_csv) --> outputs- "export_incr_20230611183316"

df = spark.read.options(header='true').csv("s3://" + f"{bucket}" + "/" + f"{directory_remote}" + "/" + f"{myfile}", schema=schema)
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Did you try spark.read.csv("s3://kp-landing-dev/input/kp/kp/") ?

Comment: thank you for your reply. It works, however, there are other files in the folder which I don't want to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("s3://kp-landing-dev/input/kp/kp/*.csv")
```